# Haskell: "Not in scope: '>>'" with no implicit prelude

Tags: haskell, ghc

Compiling the following Haskell program with GHC 6.12.1 yields an error:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude #-}

module Example where

import Prelude(Integer, fromInteger, (==))

f :: Integer -> Integer
f n
    | n == 0 = 0
```

Namely:

> example.hs:9:6: Not in scope: `>>'

The error goes away when I change the import statement to:

```
import Prelude(Integer, fromInteger, (==), (>>))
```

This makes sense. What I don't understand, however, why there is an error in the first place. My program doesn't seem to make use of any Monad, while `>>` is one of the Monad operators.

Comment: That's weird! I've added a nonsense definition like `(>>) = "blah"` and it still typechecks and works as expected; `(>>)` isn't called at all, as far as I can tell. For what it's worth, your first version works unmodified in GHC 7.0.2.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know the root cause of this problem, but if you compile your code with `-ddump-rn-trace` option on, you can see that the compiler for some reason puts `(>>)` into a list of definitions used, something like that:

```
    finish Dus [(Nothing, [(314, Integer)]),
            (Just [(rdd, f)], [(01D, >>), (01E, fromInteger), (01L, ==)]),
            (Nothing, [])]
```

Most certainly it is a bug in GHC 6.12.1

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in ghc.  You should report it.

Answer (score 1):

I can imagine the compiler checks to see if >> is present (which it needs for compilation of do-blocks), no matter if do occurs in your code.
(But then, it should also complain about >>=)